# In Bitbake use existing debian maintainer script

Tags: linux, debian, bitbake, openembedded

I have a bitbake recipe whose source is a debian package that is already built. The recipe is essentially:

```
SRC_URI = "file:///some/path/some_file.deb"
S = "${WORKDIR}/some_file"
inherit bin_package
```

I'd like to use the existing `postinst`, `preinst` and `prerm` that are already present in `some_file.deb`. I built the ipk with just the recipe above and those files weren't in the `control.tar.gz` inside the ipk that was produced.

I could also unpack the debian manually and paste the scripts into `pkg_prerm` etc., but I thought there might be a more standard bitbake way of accomplishing it in addition to automatically staying in sync with the upstream scripts.

Comment: So, your .deb file contains `postinst`, `preinst` and `prerm` scripts, and you want to supply these files to your image? By "I built the ipk" you mean that your image uses ipk format, and you are talking about file that contains your package data? And what is the `control.tar.gz`, archive that contains the image you are building?